# Odoo15 PDF Report Page Break Overlap Issue

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, odoo, pdf-generation, odoo-15

I have a problem with generating PDF reports in Odoo 15. The content of the first page overlaps with the second page, splitting some lines and table rows in half. This happens regardless of the text size or font. I tried adjusting the bottom margin, but it did not solve the issue in all cases. Here is an image that shows the problem while breaking the page:

[image]

Comment: looks more like the footer and header are overlapping the content, which i only know from the header, when the used paperformat's `header_spacing` is bigger than the `margin_top`. Other possibilites: you have negative margins anywere in your content. And also an advise: try to avoid lot of content in table cells like the devil.